# Calling node api through postman with response as enable javascript error

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, ionic-framework, https

When calling API https://mywebsite.com/api/register through browser and it returns correct response from server as { "error": false, "message": "Hello World" }

If we hit the same request from postman then it returns with some html content as Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.

Below is node side code:

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var router = express.Router();

var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', "extended": false }));

router.get("/", function (req, res) {

  res.json({ "error": false, "message": "Hello World" });

});
```

The api working through the browser but not with postman. What will be the possible errors?

Comment: Can you share what html content you are receiving as response in postman ?

Comment: html is too large to share. It is having one tag <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>

Comment: Check the generated request code in postman to get a deeper view.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to separate the **router** files then use the following pattern otherwise use `app.get()`

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    car    = require('./routes/car'),
    bus    = require('./routes/bus');

var app = express();

app.use('/car',  car);
app.use('/bus',  bus);    

app.listen(2000);
```

**car.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('GET handler for /car route.');
});

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('POST handler for /car route.');
});

router.put('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('put handler for /car route.');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Router is working fine with app.use('/api', router);
The problem is getting API response in browser, but not through the postman

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var router = express.Router();
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', "extended": false }));
app.listen(8080);
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
res.json({ "error": false, "message": "Hello World" });
});
```

Replace router.get with app.get. 
I test your code on my browser and it doesn't work too.